# How can I easily switch between my home network and a corporate VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I work from home and have a Cisco 8000 series router on my desk that provides VPN connectivity to my company's network. The router sits between my ISP-provided router and my computer. While I am connected to the VPN router, I am unable to access other computers/printers on my home network.

Is there a way I can easily switch between the VPN connection and a connection to my home network (bypass the VPN router) without having to disconnect network cables each time? Is there a device I can hook up to allow this? Or a configuration on the router?

I don't need all of the in-depth details (especially if the changes are needed at the router), but rather a good starting place to work from. I can do the research - I just don't know where to start.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure 2 network adapters in your computer in a such way that the default routing would go through your home LAN and only routing to your company internal network would go through the VPN connection.

Comment: Do you have an example configuration I can see? Url?

Comment: If you are using windows; plug in second network adapter and a cable to each network, then in the network adapters window select advanced->advanced settings, and you can prioritize the network adapters, just make sure your home one is above the work one and it will be the default.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your comment so much as pointing out an alternative -

It sounds to me like your computer is connected as follows:

Internet ---  ISP Router ---- VPN Router ---- Your PC

while Other computers are connected

Internet ---- ISP Router ---- Their PC.

Typically an office configuration would put all the PC's behind the VPN router.  This should not require much in way of hardware (probably nothing, maybe a switch).  Unless your administrator had very good reason for setting it up this way - ie to deliberately isolate you - in which case the answer is "don't use printer etc while connected to VPN), you should consider finding a new network administrator.